# Linux send URL my IP address on startup

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

So, I'm trying to write a simple bash script to send my internal IP address to a website of mine on startup. I am on a network with DHCP, so I don't always know what the IP address of my Raspberry Pi will be after I do a reboot over ssh. I figured I could fix this by sending my website the current IP on startup. I haven't written many bash scripts, and I'm not really sure how to send data to my website. Right now I was just trying in the terminal this:

```
wget -qO- http://http://mywebsite.com/private/CurrentIP.php?send=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0|grep 'inet addr:')
```

But I'm not having any luck. I don't actually know much about linux, and I'm trying to learn. That's why I got the raspberry pi actually. Anyway, can someone head me in the right direction?

I already know I need to put it in /etc/init.d/.

Comment: what's the problem more specifically?

Comment: I basically don't know how to send my IP to a website in the URL.

Comment: assuming that you are calling wget from RPi, wouldn't it make more sense just to make the request without any data and read the request's IP in PHP, as it would be the same? Also, an alternative solution would be to use dynamic dns.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm trying to get the internal network IP address. I'm only connecting to the RPi inside the network. That's why I need to send that data to the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
IP_ADDR=$(ifconfig eth0 | sed -rn 's/^.*inet addr:(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+).*$/\1/p')
wget -q -O /dev/null http://mywebsite.com/private/CurrentIP.php?send=${IP_ADDR}
```

...but if your machine is stuck behind NAT, `$IP_ADDR` won't be your externally-visible address.  Might want to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in your PHP instead of/in addition to this to get the address for your client that your server sees.

---

Edit: Sounds like you want to be able to find your Raspberry Pi on your local (DHCP-managed) network after reboots.  Have you considered using Multicast DNS instead?

How it works in practice: Let's say you've set the hostname of your RasPi to `gooseberry`.  If you've enabled a multicast DNS server on that machine, other computers on the same network segment that can send multicast DNS queries will be able to find it at the domain name `gooseberry.local`.  This is a peer-to-peer protocol and not dependent on `gooseberry` receiving any specific address via DHCP - so if it reboots and receives a new address, other machines should still be able to find it.

Mac OS X has this enabled out of the box; this can be enabled on most Linux distros (on Debian/Ubuntu you'd install the `avahi-daemon` and `libnss-mdns` packages); not sure about Windows, but a quick Google shows encouraging results.

Comment: Thanks - though having read the comments under the OP I suspect multicast DNS may be less of a headache for you than manually keeping track of the address (see edit).  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (wget part untested, but it finds IP address):

```
interface="eth0"
ip_addr=$(ifconfig ${interface} | sed -rn 's/^.*inet *([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}).*$/\1/p')
wget -q -O /dev/null http://mywebsite.com/private/CurrentIP.php?send=${ip_addr}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use:

hostname --ip-address

Comment: Normally it return 127.0.0.1

Comment: How about /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2